# Lotus Notes won't open link in embedded browser

Tags: email, browser, lotus-notes

We are developing an application that will send email notifications to users in our company's network.

There's two ways for a user to access to their account email: through the Lotus Notes desktop application and the Lotus Notes web application. The Lotus Notes version used is 8.5.3.

If the link is clicked from the web application, the web page we sent in the email is opened without a problem. But when we click on the link on the desktop application, the web page is opened in the Lotus Notes' embedded browser, which throws the following error message:

ERROR
El documento solicitado (URL https://MY.WEBPAGE.COM) no se ha podido cargar.
Se ha producido un error durante el reconocimiento SSL

(Rough translation: "The requested document (URL https://MY.WEBPAGE.COM) failed to load. There was an error during the SSL handshake")

We know the default browser can be changed, but not every user has the liberty due to company regulations.

What is causing this problem? Is there a workaround this? Can we launch the default web browser without tampering with Lotus Notes configuration?

Comment: There are two possibilities: the http server you are connecting to uses an SSL certificate that the Notes client can't authenticate, or the http server you are connecting to is using a cipher that the Notes client does not support. If it's a certificate issue, you will have to add the required certificate to end-users' names.nsf files. If it's a cipher issue, then I'm not sure what your options are - or even if you have any options. More detailed information would be needed. (Leaving this as a comment since I don't have enough info for a full answer.)

Comment: I think the first option isn't viable since the email administrator won't allow it. For the second option, what other information do you require?

Comment: You need to see exactly what's happening during the SSL handshake. I'm sorry, but I don't recall what settings you would have to turn on in the Notes client in order to get it to log info. (I'm not even sure if there are any settings for tracing SSL connections in the client. There is a setting DEBUG_SSL_ALL for the Domino server, but you're talking about the Notes client and I don't see any references indicating that that setting works in the client.)

Comment: We have received links that open on the browser, but we don't know how those links are read by Lotus Notes or even if there is a way to specify the default browser. Any ideas on that?

Comment: User's can specify the default browser on the "Internet Browser" tab within their Location preferences.

Comment: It seems we'll have to go with that, we wanted to find a way to open the web page correctly in Lotus, but it seems it's not possible. Can you post that comment as an answer so i can accept it?